# WCFFacility and WVF 4.0 REST

Tags: wcf, rest, castle-windsor, wcffacility

How do you use the Windsor-Castle WCFFacility with the WCF 4.0 REST services ?

How you you make the link to the factory, when you don't have the .svc file anymore?

TIA

Søren

Comment: Can I ask, did I answer your question (below)? Could you possibly mark it as the accepted answer if I did? (that is the tick next to the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Windsor 3.0 this is pretty straightforward (if I have understood your question correctly, my apologies if I am missing something).

The simplest thing to do to show you is to create a console application and make sure you are referencing:

- Castle.Core
- Castle.Windsor
- Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration
- System.ServiceModel
- System.ServiceModel.Web
- System.Runtime.Serialization

Now define a RESTful service like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Frob
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Fribble { get; set; }
}   

[ServiceContract]
public interface IFrobService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
    IEnumerable<Frob> GetAllFrobs();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{name}")]
    Frob GetFrobByName(string name);
}

public class FrobService : IFrobService
{
    private readonly List<Frob> _frobs
        = new List<Frob>
              {
                  new Frob {Name = "Foob", Fribble = "Soop"},
                  new Frob {Name = "Hoob", Fribble = "Soop"},
                  new Frob {Name = "Doob", Fribble = "Noop"}
              };

    public IEnumerable<Frob> GetAllFrobs()
    {
        return _frobs;
    }

    public Frob GetFrobByName(string name)
    {
        return _frobs
            .FirstOrDefault(f =>
                            f.Name.Equals(name,
                                          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Now you have that you can hook up that service into the windsor container like so (and since it is a console application, I will just show you the main method):

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {            
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container
            .AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero)
            .Register(Component.For<IFrobService>()
                          .ImplementedBy<FrobService>()
                          .AsWcfService(new RestServiceModel("http://localhost/frobs")));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And that is a WCF REST service hosted by Castle Windsor.

Pointing a browser at: "http://localhost/frobs" will get you all the frobs and pointing a browser at, say, "http://localhost/frobs/Doob" will get you the frob called Doob, you get the idea...